# SIGABRT doesn't terminate Passenger RackApp process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, phusion

Passenger 4.0.59 on RHEL 6.6 managing a Ruby 2.1.5 / Rails 3.2.18 application under Apache 2.2.15.

When I choose a random RackApp process and send it "SIGABRT" (kill -6) it correctly emits a back trace to the Apache error log, but doesn't subsequently terminate.

Shouldn't it die after spitting out the back trace?  Is the failure-to-die somehow related to my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/JWmo4XQ-K0c

Will be fixed in 5.0.11.